# How can I use XSLT 2.0 and XSLT 3.0 in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am able to use XSLT 1.0 in Java as shown in the folllowing example :-

copy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="identityxfm.xsl"?>
<catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>        
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with
 XML.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk102">
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <title>Midnight Rain</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
        <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,
 an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the
 world.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk103">
        <author>Corets, Eva</author>
        <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
        <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology society
 in England, the young survivors lay the foundation for a new 
society.</description>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

copy.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

  <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Copy.java

```
package com.data.transform;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Copy {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource("copy.xml");
        StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource("copy.xsl");

        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(stylesource);

        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        transformer.transform(source, result);
      }
}
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="identityxfm.xsl"?><catalog>
    <book id="bk101">
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>        
        <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with
 XML.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk102">
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <title>Midnight Rain</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
        <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies,
 an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the
 world.</description>
    </book>
    <book id="bk103">
        <author>Corets, Eva</author>
        <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
        <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
        <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology society
 in England, the young survivors lay the foundation for a new 
society.</description>
    </book>
</catalog>
```

But, now I want to use few things that are included in XSLT 2.0 and XSLT 3.0 (like `xsl:analyze-string`, `xsl:try` etc.) in Java. How can I do that ?

Comment: Use a Java library implementing that. Search the web to find one.

Answer (score 10):

Get Saxon 9 HE from Maven or [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/) and put it on the classpath, then you have XSLT 2.0 support with Saxon 9.x before 9.8 or XSLT 3.0 support (except streaming, higher order functions, `xsl:evaluate`, schema-awareness, backwards compatibility) with 9.8. For full XSLT 3.0 support you need [to download Saxon 9 PE or EE from Saxonica](http://saxonica.com/download/download_page.xml) and put it together with a [license](http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/about/license/) you buy or a trial licence you request on the classpath.

Comment: I did that. Now I am able to use XSLT 2, but I am still getting error for XSLT 3, as the keywords (that are introduced in XSLT 3) are not recognized. Any other way to use XSLT 3 in Java ?

Comment: Please provide details as to what you did exactly, start by reading the documentation of Saxon, in particular http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/about/license/ to see and check whether you run PE or EE properly with a license. See also http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/embedding/jaxp-transformation.html.  If you still have problems post the details as to what you did and which error messages you get, preferably in the Saxon Help forum https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/boards or here with a new question tagged as saxon.