# Bean creation issues with XsltPayloadTransformer due to [ERR 0512] Cannot continue because of stylesheet errors in Websphere 9

Tags: java, xslt, spring-integration, websphere

We are using spring integration(*spring-integration-core:jar:5.0.14.RELEASE*) in our project.  Our application is working fine in JBOSS 7 EAP. Now we want to make it compatible with **Websphere 9** Application sever. We are getting the following error when we deploy the application in **Websphere 9** and try to access it. It appears that there is some problem with **int-xml:xslt-transformer** . Any incompatible XSLT processors causing this issue?  Any help on how to proceed further to fix this problem would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
  [10/14/20 4:00:35:585 CDT] 000000e8 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[SpringDispatcherServlet]: **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.xml.transformer.XsltPayloadTransformer#540': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException: [ERR 0512] Cannot continue because of stylesheet errors.**
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$148.000000003A5547E0.getObject(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at .(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:881)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:409)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1836)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:442)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1248)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1578)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:707)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1153)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:800)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1450)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2311)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:654)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5574)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5700)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:668)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:612)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1340)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:83)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor94.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:287)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1263)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:673)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1257)
        at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1096)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:831)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:813)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1350)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1243)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
        at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
        at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1833)
        at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
        at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
        at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1909)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException: [ERR 0512] Cannot continue because of stylesheet errors.
        at org.springframework.integration.xml.transformer.XsltPayloadTransformer.onInit(XsltPayloadTransformer.java:248)
        at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(IntegrationObjectSupport.java:176)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1746)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1683)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$148.000000003A5547E0.getObject(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at .(Unknown Source)
        ... 64 more
    Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException: [ERR 0512] Cannot continue because of stylesheet errors.
        at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.AbstractTransformerFactory.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.integration.xml.transformer.XsltPayloadTransformer.onInit(XsltPayloadTransformer.java:245)
        at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(IntegrationObjectSupport.java:176)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1746)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1683)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$148.000000003A5547E0.getObject(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at .(Unknown Source)
        ... 64 more
    Caused by: com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.HandledRuntimeException: [ERR 0512] Cannot continue because of stylesheet errors.
        at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.ConfigurationErrorHandler.report(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xtq.utils.Reporter.report(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xtq.ast.parsers.xslt.XSLTParser.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.drivers.XSLTCompiler.compile(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.compiler.TransformerFactoryImpl.createTemplates(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.xtq.xslt.jaxp.AbstractTransformerFactory.newTemplates(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.integration.xml.transformer.XsltPayloadTransformer.onInit(XsltPayloadTransformer.java:245)
        at org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.afterPropertiesSet(IntegrationObjectSupport.java:176)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1746)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1683)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$148.000000003A5547E0.getObject(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
        at .(Unknown Source)
        ... 64 more
```

Comment: Your question is not readable. Please, consider to edit it the way StackOverflow lets us for format the code and logs. Otherwise it feels rude to see such a text.

Comment: @Artem Bilan, I am sorry.. I formatted the log now. Please take a look now.

Comment: Thanks. You probably need to ask IBM support for the solution. Looks like their built-in parser doesn't support XSLT 2.0: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=900463. You probably can replace a built-in one with  Saxon somehow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317022/how-can-i-use-xslt-2-0-and-xslt-3-0-in-java, but that's out of my WebSphere knowlage...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, found the following:

The issue is resolved by changing the default XSLT processor to XSLT interpreter.

For this:

1. Go to Servers -> Application servers -> [Server_Name] -> Proces
   Definition -> Java and Process Management -> Java Virtual Machine
2. In this section add the following argument:
   "***-Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl***"
   to the input labelled "**Generic JVM arguments**"
3. Submit the form by clicking the "OK" button, then commit changes by
   clicking the "Save" link. This change needs a restart of IBM
   WebSphere Application Server to take effect.